# How can I subtract two svn patch files?

Tags: svn, patch

I would like to have a patch-queue system (like those offered by guilt or mercurial-mq) on top of SVN.

SVN is already able to export patch files, which represent the difference from the remote to the working copy. I can already use this, and create a patch every time I change something, but that patch would also contain all the previous changes I made. This doesn't usually create problems when applying the patch, because the redundant parts will be ignored.

Even so, I would like my patches to only contain the changes I made from the last patch I saved to the current working copy, so that they will be more flexible. I can delete a patch to "revert" it, or I can choose to apply only a subset of the patches. In order to do this, I think the only thing I need is a tool that can subtract two patches.

For instance, given 001.patch:

```
Index: myrepo/myfile.h
===================================================================
--- myrepo/myfile.h (revision 200)
+++ myrepo/myfile.h (working copy)
@@ -283,1 +283,1 @@
    void f();
```

and 002.tmp.patch:

```
Index: myrepo/myfile.h
===================================================================
--- myrepo/myfile.h (revision 200)
+++ myrepo/myfile.h (working copy)
@@ -283,1 +283,1 @@
    void f();

Index: myrepo/myfile.c
===================================================================
--- myrepo/myfile.c (revision 200)
+++ myrepo/myfile.c (working copy)
@@ -283,1 +283,1 @@
    void f() { }
```

I would like to obtain 002.patch:

```
Index: myrepo/myfile.c
===================================================================
--- myrepo/myfile.c (revision 200)
+++ myrepo/myfile.c (working copy)
@@ -283,1 +283,1 @@
    void f() { }
```

Of course, this is much less obvious when things are removed or modified. Anyway, I'd be happy enough with a hunk-level subtraction (one that just takes 002.tmp.patch and removes all the hunks which have an identical copy in 001.patch)

Answer (score 0):

The `interdiff` tool can do exactly what I asked for.
http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/interdiff1.html